# Oracle - Compare column using REGEXP_LIKE

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

I have a table containing 2 columns:   FIRST_PART, SECOND_PART.    What I need is to run a query again another table using the FIRST_PART, SECOND_PART as LIKE.

So, something like:    SELECT {fields} FROM {table} WHERE {column} LIKE {first_part}%{second_part}

I thought maybe some string I construct and use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, but there must be another way......

Comment: Sample data and expected output would be helpful here

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT field1,
       field2,
       field3
FROM   table_name t
WHERE  EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
  FROM   other_table o
  WHERE  t.column_name LIKE o.first_part || '%' || o.second_part
);
```